# How can i use LINQ Aggregate here?

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to optimise the following code into 1 line using LINQ Aggregate, however never used Aggregate function before and although I tried, I couldn't make it work..

```
var sum = Aggregate(0.0, (group) => group.width + ????);
```

instead of

```
double sum = 0.0;
double height = 1.0;
foreach (var group in Groups)
{
sum = sum + group.width;
}

var rectPosition = new Rectangular(anchor.x, anchor.y,new BoxDimension(sum, height ));
```

Any assistance please.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To tell the truth this is enough:

```
var sum = Groups.Select(x => x.Width).Sum();
var sum = Groups.Sum(x => x.Width);
```

But, if you want `Aggregate()`:

```
var sum = Groups.Select(x => x.Width).Aggregate((current, next) => current += next);
```

Comment: jeez of course ! How easy...sorry guys its friday today my mind is set for the weekend!